# CoreBluetooth Characteristic value

Tags: ios, iphone, core-bluetooth

I'm confused on how long the value of a characteristic for CBMutableCharacteristic can be. If I have an archived array of objects, can I set the value of the Characteristic to this archived array? Or am I better off having a separate characteristic for each archived object in the array?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The specification limits the maximum length of a characteristic value in 512 octets (Bluetooth specification V4.0 Vol 3. Part F 3.2.9). On the central side you start a read request with the `readValueForCharacteristic:` API. Then on the peripheral side you receive the corresponding callback:

```
CBMutableCharacteristic *characteristic = // the characteristic with long data

- (void)peripheralManager:(CBPeripheralManager *)peripheral didReceiveReadRequest:(CBATTRequest *)request {
  // Ensure offset is in the valid range
  if (request.offset > characteristic.value.length) {
   // respond with error
   [self.peripheralManager respondToRequest:request withResult:CBATTErrorInvalidOffset];  
   return;
  }

  NSRange range = NSMakeRange(request.offset, characteristic.value.length - request.offset);
  request.value = [characteristic.value subdataWithRange:range];

  [self.peripheralManager respondToRequest:request withResult:CBATTErrorSuccess];  
}
```

The callback will be called with increasing `offset` values as long as the response is not less than the Maximum Transferrable Unit (MTU). The MTU is negotiated by the system and you have no way to query it in advance. For this reason the `range` is set up to stretch all the way to the data length so the system can decide how much of the data it is going to send to the central. By default it is 20 but iOS 7 has some tweaks that enable greater sizes. Check out the WWDC videos for more detail.

With this info you should be able to figure out a way to expose your data. Keep in mind that the more services and characteristics you have, the longer the discovery will take. Using long reads and long writes is just a convenience.

Comment: @HakimHauston "octets" means bytes, the maximum length is thus 512 bytes.

Comment: Does anyone have the equivalent of "characteristic.value.length" in Swift?

Answer (score 1):

This project may be exactly what you're looking for: [SimpleShare](http://github.com/lauraskelton/simple-share)

It uses Bluetooth LE to share arrays of strings between devices. The technique is to use just one characteristic to share the data, but when a central subscribes to the characteristic, the peripheral changes the value to each new piece of data it wants to send, until the entire too-long message is sent. Basically, it breaks it down into bite-sized chunks that fit in the characteristic and sends them one at a time.

Hope that helps!